# Table view content disappear on horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, tableview

I have UIScrollView with 3x Screen Size width, and i have 3 table view in it. For some reason, content disappear in some point of time when i begin to scroll horizontally. But tables are on screen (i can figure that out because i set tables background colour and can see it). Also, i did print items in number of rows and it exist. Here is my code:

```
func createTables(){




  for i in 0...2 {

    var tv : UITableView
    var adapter : CDRTableAdapter
    var tvVm : MainTableViewModel
    let offset = (CGFloat(i) * CGFloat(Helper.ScreenSize.width))
    print("offset \(offset)")

    /* View model */

    tvVm = MainTableViewModel()

    /* Table view */

    adapter = CDRTableAdapter(model:tvVm as CDTableAdapterViewModel, managedVC: self)

    let dct = ["EmptyHeightItem" : "EmptyHeightCell", "MenuItem" : "MenuCell"]

    tv = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    tv.separatorStyle = .none
        if (i == 1){
    tv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }   else {
            tv.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    tv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tv.mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary: dct)
    tv.dataSource = adapter
    tv.delegate = adapter
    tv.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    tv.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.mainContainerView.addSubview(tv)

    tv.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in

        make.top.equalTo(self.segmentioView.snp.bottom)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.mainContainerView)
        make.left.equalTo(self.mainContainerView).offset(offset)
        make.width.equalTo(Helper.ScreenSize.width)
    }

    }
}

extension UITableView {

    func mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary : [String : String]) -> Void {

        for (key, _) in dictionary {
            let cellClassStr = "\(Helper.appName).\(dictionary[key]!)"
            self.register(NSClassFromString(cellClassStr), forCellReuseIdentifier: key)
        }

    }
}
```

So, if someone has faced the problem before please help.
Thanks

Comment: mapTableViewWithCellsDictionary(dictionary: dct)...Show this method as well

Comment: @Ishika i updated it.

Comment: This codes looks ok,  if you are calling `createTables` only once.

Comment: @JonSnow it does call only once. Where to find possible bug?

Comment: put it in `viewDidLoad` Method

Comment: @JonSnow i found problem. It was related somehow to https://github.com/Yalantis/Segmentio, i did add to top of container view (that are in scrollView).